# How to mitigate this "Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request" when trying to post a build trigger to perforce

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

According to https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219152268-Use-POST-Commit-Hook-with-Perforce-Triggers I have to use the following to post a trigger to build.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The first argument is the change number
CHANGE=$1

# POST the payload
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --request POST \ 
     --data "{\"change\":$CHANGE, \"p4port\":\"localhost:1666\"}" \
     http://localhost:8080/p4/change
```

I've modified that a bit to add my port and change number after which it started giving me the crumb not found issue.

After reading this [How to request for the crumb issuer for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16738441/7504076) and [Spinnaker: 403 No valid crumb was included in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44711696/7504076) I first tried to disable CSRF, but this gave me a 404, so I tried with it enabled, got the crumb and embedded it like so which again gives me a 404.

```
curl -X POST http://username:password@jenkinsip:8080/p4/change -H "Jenkins-Crumb:the-crumb" --data "{\"change\":$CHANGE, \"p4port\":\"myport\"}"
```

But if I try this I get the same 403 error again.

```
curl -X POST http://jenkinsip:8080/p4/change -H "Jenkins-Crumb:the-crumb" --data "{\"change\":$CHANGE, \"p4port\":\"myport\"}"
```

So what am I doing wrong that it is giving me a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before requesting Jenkins to trigger a build based on your new perforce change you need to request a crumb from Jenkins and include the response in your request.

The following trigger script works for us:

```
#!/bin/bash
CHANGE=$1

P4PORT=<perforceserver>:<portnumber>
JUSER=<jenkinsuser>
JPASS=<hispassword>
JSERVER=https://<jenkinsserver>

# Get CRUMB
CRUMB=$(curl --insecure --silent --user $JUSER:$JPASS $JSERVER/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat\(//crumbRequestField,%22":"%22,//crumb\))

curl --header "$CRUMB" \
     --request POST \
     --insecure \
     --silent \
     --user $JUSER:$JPASS \
     --data payload="{change:$CHANGE,p4port:\"$P4PORT\"}" \
     $JSERVER/p4/change
```

**Update**:
I just discovered that I've once stolen the above script from the documentation for the Jenkins Perforce Plugin. See [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/docs/BUILDTRIGGERPERFORCE.md).

Comment: Thank you, that link really helped me.